# Ubuntu 12.04 server reboot issues after updates

Tags: boot, server, ssh, startup

I have a 12.04 LTS ubuntu server (I used the how to forge guide to setup apache, php, postfix, dovecot, bind and ISPConfig).

I have noticed a somehow random reboot issue which I have eventually narrowed down as described below.

**Circumstances**

When I update the server through SSH and the update needs the server to reboot (1), if I reboot through SSH, the server won't fully reboot. One or several hard reboot (i.e. pulling the plug) are required in order to take control.

**Symptoms**

- SSH is down (connexion refused).
- Apache is down (not serving any page web)
- postfix/dovecot are down (mail server unreachable).

**Questions**

I don't know wether the issue is that the server can't shutdown properly and stops when most services are down, or doesn't launch all services on reboot. How can I tell ?

How can I further track down the issue ? I can only access the server through SSH. It is located 700 km away from me. So I can't plug in a screed. Neither can I see the startup process or the shutdown since ssh is not active at those times.